# Let m ∈ N. Define the relation ≡^ on Z by a ≡^ b for a, b ∈ Z if and only if a ≡ ±b (mod m).

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-verification

(In  other  words,  the  relation ≡^  holds if either a ≡ b (mod m) or a ≡ −b  (mod m).)

Prove that the  relation  ≡^ on Z is transitive.

=======

I believe there are 3 properties that it must meet to prove and equivalence relationship. Any reference material would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As requested: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, I will write $\sim$ in place of $\equiv$^.
$$
a\sim b\implies (a+mk)^2=b^2,\quad \text{some }k\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Similarly,
$$
b\sim c\implies (c+ml)^2=b^2,\quad \text{some }l\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Putting these together, we have either
$$
a+mk = c + ml\implies a\equiv c\; (\text{mod } m)
$$
or
$$
a+mk=-c-ml\implies a\equiv -c\;(\text{mod }m).
$$

Comment: Thanks would you know what the ≡ with a ^ on top is called?